# How to merge (link) 2 Relations on different tables in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

Given 2 ActiveRecord relations that generate following SQL:

- relation `a = SELECT comments.* FROM comments INNER JOIN attachments ON attachments.comment_id = comments.id WHERE attachment.name ILIKE '%foo%`
- relation `b = SELECT attachments.* FROM attachments INNER JOIN users ON attachments.user_id = users.id WHERE users.other_conditions`

This worked in Rails/ActiveRecord **3**:

```
puts a.merge(b).to_sql # Rails 3
> "SELECT comments.* FROM comments INNER JOIN attachments ON attachments.comment_id = comments.id INNER JOIN users ON attachments.user_id = users.id WHERE attachment.name ILIKE '%foo% AND users.other_conditions"
```

I think it worked because the `merge` was ignoring any non-existing associations on the queries.

But Rails **4** is much more pedantic and fails with:

```
puts a.merge(b).to_sql # Rails 4
> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'user' was not found on Comment; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

So the question is how can I literally merge the 2 relations without Rails being worried about the correctness (my specs take responsibility for that)?

Comment: Check Arel gem that is used internally by Rails - https://github.com/rails/arel and some examples/specs here https://github.com/rails/arel/tree/master/test you might get some more insight.

Comment: @OtoBrglez can't find any pointers there. Do you have any?

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your models and their relations a little more?

For me it worked like this:

```
class User
   has_many :facebook_friends
end

class FacebookFriend
  belongs_to :user
end

a = User.where("users.first_name LIKE '%Sandy%'")
b = FacebookFriend.where("facebook_friends.last_name LIKE '%John%'")
a.merge(b)
```

=> User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (users.first_name LIKE '%Sandy%') AND (facebook_friends.last_name LIKE '%John%')

=> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'facebook_friends.last_name' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (users.first_name LIKE '%Sandy%') AND (facebook_friends.last_name LIKE '%John%')

```
a.joins(:facebook_friends).merge(b)
```

=> User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `facebook_friends` ON `facebook_friends`.`user_uid` = `users`.`uid` WHERE (users.first_name LIKE '%Sandy%') AND (facebook_friends.last_name LIKE '%John%')

=> []

Answer (score 0):

The amazing [scuttle.io](http://www.scuttle.io/) transforms your sql as follows:

```
Comment.select(Comment.arel_table[Arel.star]).where(
  Attachment.arel_table[:name].and(User.arel_table[:other_conditions])
).joins(
  Comment.arel_table.join(Attachment.arel_table).on(
    Attachment.arel_table[:comment_id].eq(Comment.arel_table[:id])
  ).join_sources
).joins(
  Comment.arel_table.join(User.arel_table).on(
    Attachment.arel_table[:user_id].eq(User.arel_table[:id])
  ).join_sources
)
```